# JComboBox and JButton (2 columns) and keep JComboBox as big as possible?

Tags: java, layout, combobox

I'm programming a form for some data. One row of this form contains a JComboBox to choose an element from it. Right next to it is a JButton to add elements to this JComboBox. Basically everything works right, except the Layout.

The form has a fixed width, scaling is completely disabled. How can I achieve that the JButton is to the right of the JComboBox, while the JComboBox is still as big as possible?

I'm using the program on Windows and Mac OS and have some issues with the button size, so setting a fixed width for the two columns/components is not really an option.

So it should look like this:

`````````````````
|<------- fixed width ------->|

|-----------------------------|
| Form:                       |
|-----------------------------|
|  ________________   ______  |
| |ComboBox       v| |Button| |
|  ````````````````   ``````  |
|                             |
| ...                         |
|                             |
|-----------------------------|
`````````````````

Or when the button is smaller:

``````````````````````
|-----------------------------|
| Form:                       |
|-----------------------------|
|  _____________________   _  |
| |ComboBox            v| |+| |
|  `````````````````````   `  |
|                             |
| ...                         |
|                             |
|-----------------------------|
``````````````````````

Note that if the content in the ComboBox is too long, it should be shortened similar to this:

```````````````````````
 ______________________
|ComboBoxContentFo... v|
 ``````````````````````
```````````````````````

Would be happy if someone can help me out with this! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take advantage of layout managers to do this for you.

One way is to use a BorderLayout:

```
JPanel row = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
row.add(comboBox, BorderLayout.CENTER);
row.add(button, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
mainPanel.add( row );
```

Now the button will be displayed at its preferred width and the combo box will get whatever is left over.

Comment: This works more or less, but the problem here is, that even when I set a maximum size for the panel, the JComboBox won't shorten the text inside. Therefore the panel-width is bigger than the max allowed width for this panel.

Comment: @Exceen, it works fine for me with a simple JFrame containing the button and the combo box. Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Ah, never mind. It works fine when I do it like you said and add `comboBox.setPrototypeDisplayValue("X");`. The difference here is probably, that you use it in the 'main-panel' and I use it in the 100th-sub-panel if you know what I mean. Also my panel is inside a ScrollPane.

Answer (score 0):

You can try those two things.

```
comboBox.setPreferredSize(...)
```

or

```
comboBox.setPrototypeDisplayValue("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
```

Comment: As said, the width of the JComboBox needs to be adjusted dynamically (depending on the button-width), so `.setPreferredSize(...)` is no option.